# 400 "bad request" after tomcat installation on kubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, tomcat, kubuntu

I've installed Tomcat 6.0.18 on my kubuntu machine following [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/) but I got a 400 response when I try to reach http://127.0.0.1:8080

I also try to install it on a different PC with Ubuntu and everything was ok...

Any clue???

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a proxy configured for your Kubuntu machine? If so, does the traffic accidentally go through the proxy even when surfing http://127.0.0.1:8080/? Have you tried to `telnet localhost 8080` and then enter `GET / HTTP/1.0` or so?

Answer (score -1):

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Comment: ??? I don't know how this could help...